# Compare multiple columns with the same values, but some rows missing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am downloading ranking data from Google Webmaster Tools for specific time periods and it looks like this (columns):

Keyword - Position

The Keywords differ for each time period, as well as the position.

This week there may be 20 keywords. Next week there maybe 40 (eg 15 of the previous week, some new ones, some of the old ones are out etc)

I want An excel Sheet which looks like this:

Keyword - Position_timeperiod1 - Position_timeperiod2 - Position_timeperiod3.. etc

How do I do that?

In pics:
[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or format your text as a table? Thanks.

Comment: Added screenshpot for clarification

Comment: Added answer below

Comment: I realize this is probably just mocked up text but I'm worried about what activity requires bears, couches, mountains of fruit, and 77 condoms.

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own workbook to illustrate a way to do this. There are many ways but I feel this way is relatively simple.

[image]

The stuff to the left is layed out like how you receive it. Notice that there is a pattern that every 4 columns, it is repeated. We will use this to our advantage.

The first step is to create one list of everything. I have created 3 columns to capture the column on, row on, and if to switch columns:

[image] [image] [image]

**Note:** I used $A$2:$E$12 as my static range but adjust this to include a really big area for your data so it can take into account more data. This same range is used in my other formulas.

Now we simply compile our list:

[image]

**At this point our list is made so we simply need to populate the values**

I put a column field above each period to reference where it is looking. This could be automated later on if you wish since it is just adding 3 each time:

[image]

Now simply drag our formulas to populate everything.

This method should at least help you along your way. You may want to put all of the stuff you add on another tab (worksheet) to make it look better and hide some of the columns to make it pretty but I hope this helps!